# Building Apache 2.2 distribution with LDAP and SSL modules

Tags: linux

I am trying to build a custom Apache 2.2 binary distribution on Linux RHEL 5.3.

I first uncompress the Apache 2.2 sources.

Then, I configured the file `build/binbuild.sh` as follows:

```
CONFIGPARAM="--prefix=$BUILD_DIR --enable-deflate=shared --with-ldap --with-ssl --with-mpm=worker"
```

Finally, I run the `build/binbuild.sh` to generate the distribution.

But, when I look at the `modules` directory in the generated distribution, there is no LDAP or SSL modules, only the deflate module.

I tried with configuration `--enable-ldap --enable-ssl` but the compilation failed, there are a lot of errors.
And with `--enable-ldap --enable-ssl --with-ldap --with-ssl` it compiles but there is still no module.

What am I doing wrong ? How to add these modules to the distribution ?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: It is to have a distribution already configured "ready to install" and with only specific modules activated. This distribution will be installed on customer servers.

Comment: I would suggest to instead use the distribution-provided packages and just create an RPM of your specific configuration and place this in /etc/httpd, overriding the default config of the packages. This is a lot easier and you don't have to worry about building it again in regular intervals to security issues.

Comment: The distribution is not installed in /etc/httpd but in user's directories as there are several Apache installation on the same server. If the RPM can be installed in any directory, it could be the solution. It will just have some impacts on our installation script which are based on the Apache `install-bindist.sh`